Why is the alert not showing up on my IOS Application after clicking the button?
Form {
    // Title
    TextField("Title", text: $viewModel.title).textFieldStyle(DefaultTextFieldStyle())

    // Date
    DatePicker("Due Date", selection: $viewModel.dueDate)
        .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle()).padding(.all, 10)

    // Button
    TLButton(text: "Add to Do") {
        if viewModel.canSave {
            viewModel.save()
            newItemPresented = false
        } else {
            viewModel.showAlert = true
            print(viewModel.showAlert)
        }
    }
}
.alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert) {
    Alert(title: Text("Error"),
          message: Text("Enter Correctly"))
}

I am trying to make an alert popup when the end-user gives incorrect details on the form, which is validated by an external class.
I have declared the concerned variables in the external class as follows
@Published var title = ""
@Published var dueDate = Date()
@Published var showAlert = false

I am also attaching all relevant functions (in my opinion) to the scope of this problem:
var canSave: Bool {
    guard !title.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
        return false
    }

    guard dueDate >= Date().addingTimeInterval(-86400) else {
        return false
    }

    return true
}

My TLButton Class:

import SwiftUI

struct TLButton: View {
    let text: String
    let action: ()  -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            //Attempt log in
            action()
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(.blue)
                Text(text).foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }.padding(.bottom, 5)
    }
}

#Preview {
    TLButton(text: "Foo") {
        // action
    }
}

I tried printing the value of viewModel.showAlert to see if it updates it to true, when it is initially set to false. It does update it, however, the alert does not come. I expect the Alert to pop up with the associated image.
Edit:
How I declare the variables in my class.
@State var viewModel = NewItemViewViewModel()
@Binding var newItemPresented: Bool


You could try using
DispatchQueue.main.async { viewModel.showAlert = true }

@workingdogsupportUkraine that doesn't work unfortunately

How do you declare and pass your viewModel?
For example do you have a
@StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel() that you pass to your subview? Show a more complete code that reproduces your issue.

tested your code with my assumptions, and all works well for me. Show the code you are using, especially how you declare and pass your ViewModel

@workingdogsupportUkraine I've added it to the new edit. Do you want me to paste the entire class?

try this approach using @StateObject and class NewItemViewViewModel: ObservableObject, as in this example code.
First select a date before today, then press the button to display the alert.
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = NewItemViewViewModel() // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Title", text: $viewModel.title).textFieldStyle(DefaultTextFieldStyle())
            
            DatePicker("Due Date", selection: $viewModel.dueDate)
                .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle()).padding(.all, 10)
            
            TLButton(text: "Add to Do") {
                if viewModel.canSave {
                    viewModel.save()
                    // newItemPresented = false
                } else {
                    viewModel.showAlert = true
                    print(viewModel.showAlert)
                }
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Enter Correctly"))
        }
    }
}

class NewItemViewViewModel: ObservableObject {  // <--- here
    @Published var title = "original title"
    @Published var dueDate = Date()
    @Published var showAlert = false
    
    var canSave: Bool {
        guard !title.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return false
        }
        guard dueDate >= Date().addingTimeInterval(-86400) else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func save() { }
}


Could you explain why i should declare the variable as @StateObject

You need to use @StateObject as the source of truth of the data and to let the View observe the class NewItemViewViewModel: ObservableObject.
Have a look at this Apple link  Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app. Did my code not worked for you?
